# I have a shell script which simply starts webserver serives as the machine gets reboot

Tags: linux, bash, cron

```
#!/bin/bash

WEBSERVER=/usr/applications/jboss/bin
cd $WEBSERVER
status=`ps -aef | grep -v grep |grep -i standalone | wc -l`
if [ $status == "0" ]
then
    nohup ./standalone.sh &
else
    echo "WebServer is already running"
fi
```

I want to execute this script at startup via CRON. So I edit the crontab listing by using `crontab -e`

> @reboot /usr/siemens/applications/Start_Stop_Services/04.startJBoss_tcWebServer01_tcPreProd01.sh >> /usr/siemens/applications/Start_Stop_Services/logs/04.startJBoss_tcWebServer01_tcPreProd01.log

This is the crontab I have written, and the file has permissions to execute. I can run the file no problem as a script from the commandline. Yet when I restart the machine, no service gets started. I am trying to understand why, and played around with the crontab entry.

Comment: Why use crontab when you can create a systemd or initV service file, which are supposed to handle starting scripts ?

Comment: *ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep -qi standalone && echo "WebServer is already running" || nohub $WEBSERVER/standalone.sh &*

Comment: Hi Orsiris de Jong,
I have created crontabs for other server's as well and they are working fine, but for the webserver I'm not getting expected output.

Comment: Hello alecxs,
I'll try with this. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: My bad I have given the wrong file name in the crontab. Now Crontab is working but the service is still not getting started after starting the cronjob. Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.